# Changing University Name in gatech-thesis Document Class

Tags: classicthesis, thesis

I am trying the write a thesis using the gatech-thesis document class, but it keeps saying Georgia Institute of Technology in various places across the document. How can I change it to say the name of another university?  The class file can be found [here](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/gatech-thesis/gatech-thesis.cls).

Comment: Can you please add an link to document class? BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Have you tried searching the class file for "Georgia Institute of Technology"?  If you simply want it to say something different, then search/replace in the class file might be easiest.

Comment: @ScottH. How do I find the class file on my computer? I'm still a little new to Latex, so I don't exactly know how to find it.

Comment: @Bronzeclocksofbenin Type `kpsewhich gatech-thesis.cls` into a command prompt/terminal and navigate to the location pointed to there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the following code in `gatech-thesis.cls` file:

```
\newcommand{\title@text}{
  \begin{center}
    \ifthesisproposal
       A Thesis Proposal\\
       Presented to\\
       The Academic Faculty\\
    \else
       A \ifdissertation Dissertation\else Thesis\fi\\
       Presented to\\
       The Academic Faculty\\
    \fi
    \ \\
    by\\
    \ \\
    {\@author}\\
    \vspace*{1.1in}
    In Partial Fulfillment \\
    of the Requirements for the Degree \\
    {\@degree} in
    \iflistmajor
       \\ {\@major}\\
       \vfill
       {\@department}\\
    \else
       the\\ {\@department}\\
       \vfill
    \fi
       Georgia Institute of Technology\\%
    {\@submitdate}%
    \ifcopyright
      \\ \vspace*{.3in}% one line + 0.3in
      Copyright \copyright\ {\@copyrightyear} by {\@author}
    \fi
  \end{center}
}
```

Change the **Georgia Institute of Technology** to whatever you want.

Comment: One also has to make sure to specify the optional institution argument for `\principaladvisor`, `\committeechair`, `\firstreader` to `\sixthreader` which otherwise defaults to *Georgia Institute of Technology*.

Answer (score 1):

that is hardcoded in the class file. You have to redefine the title macro:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{gatech-thesis}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\title@text{
  \begin{center}
    \ifthesisproposal
       A Thesis Proposal\\
       Presented to\\
       The Academic Faculty\\
    \else
       A \ifdissertation Dissertation\else Thesis\fi\\
       Presented to\\
       The Academic Faculty\\
    \fi
    \ \\
    by\\
    \ \\
    {\@author}\\
    \vspace*{1.1in}
    In Partial Fulfillment \\
    of the Requirements for the Degree \\
    {\@degree} in
    \iflistmajor
       \\ {\@major}\\
       \vfill
       {\@department}\\
    \else
       the\\ {\@department}\\
       \vfill
    \fi
%       Georgia Institute of Technology\\%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        My University\\                  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    {\@submitdate}%
    \ifcopyright
      \\ \vspace*{.3in}% one line + 0.3in
      Copyright \copyright\ {\@copyrightyear} by {\@author}
    \fi
  \end{center}
}

\makeatother
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym,float,epsfig,subfigure}
\title{The Elements of Thesis}
[...]
```